# Turtles do not pets make Vs Turtles do not make pets

Tags: word-order

*"Turtles do not **pets make**"* or *"Turtles do not **make pets**"*

Which one is grammatically correct and what's the difference between both phrases?

Comment: Why do you think they have different meanings?

Comment: I'm guessing you've seen the first written somewhere. Is that right?  If so please tell us where you saw it written.

Comment: Probably https://tvquot.es/schitts-creek/quote/9wz1c3x/,  a quote from a tv show Schitts Creek

Comment: @JamesK - If that's the correct source, then it's relevant that the character of Moira Rose often speaks in a stilted, overly-dramatic way. Her dialog should not be used as a guide to colloquial English!

Answer (score 2):

"A turtle does not a pet make" is an unsuccessful attempt to replace words in the expression, "*One swallow does not a summer make...*".

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_swallow_does_not_a_summer_make#Etymology), this is a word-for-word translation of a quote from the ancient Greek philosopher Aristotle.

This expression literally means, "*There are lots of swallows in the summer, but seeing one swallow doesn't mean it's summer.*" The intended deeper meaning is, "*If something happens that's associated with a particular event, it doesn't mean that event is happening.*"

So your case with a turtle as a pet doesn't fit the expression. It would mean something like, "The existence of turtles doesn't mean there's a pet". I'm not sure what the intent of the original turtle sentence is, but I'm sure it's not that.

Answer (score 1):

The first, while probably grammatical, is not idiomatic and will strike most English speakers as a poetic form of expression, and probably remind them of sayings such as *stone walls do not a prison make*, (where *make* is used in a slightly different sense from your example).

There is no difference in meaning.